# Small format X terminal with EL screen

Tags: unix, terminal, xwindow-x11

I remember an ad for a small-format (about as wide as a 60% keyboard) dark-ish grey colored X terminal that had a 12" (?) yellow electroluminescent screen similar to the Grid laptops but higher resolution. Does anyone remember it or can identify it?

Comment: One of the Visual technologies devices ?

Comment: None I could identify. It had a format reminiscent of the Apricot portable, but with a narrower screen.